# Viewport Display and Base Color in Solid Display 2.8

Tags: materials

is there a way to link the base color of an object and the viewport display color in solid mode? or do you have to separately assign the color to see it. Just want to avoid switching back and forth between eevee, cycles and solid mode on my weak computer.

Comment: Are you talking about a dynamic link that updates when you change the base color? Bc. each material has a viewport display setting. at the very bottom (properties tab) where you can set it manually. 
Linking probably won't work, because there can be numerous "base colors" in a material.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz ok

Comment: I can write you a script that tries to find a shader node and uses its first color input as the VP color, but you'd have to run that everytime you add a new object.

Comment: All good, I have already accepted I have to change the color twice. Thank you